# pass file name to script

Tags: python, xml

I found the following script to split XML files.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
context = ET.iterparse('BGSM_VPAY_D-001565_20180315-220009-049.xml', events=('e$
index = 0
for event, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == 'Payment_Ack':
        index += 1
        filename = format(str(index) + ".xml")
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
            f.write(ET.tostring(elem))
```

How do I change this to pass the filename 'BGSM_VPAY_D-001565_20180315-220009-049.xml' and all the other files in the same folder with BGSM_VPAY at the start.
I also need to output the file with the same filename, but with 001, 002 etc at the end (but before the xml extention).

thanks
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use `glob`:

```
import glob
fnames = glob.glob('BGSM_VPAY*')
```

To add a number `i` before the '.xml' extension:

```
output_fname = fname[:-4] + '.' + str(i).zfill(3) + '.xml'
```

Note that this currently also adds a dot before the number, e.g. `'BGSM_VPAY_D-001565_20180315-220009-049.001.xml'`